# Is it possible to generate data with peak and x y location?

Tags: python, math, plotly, analytics, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to create a 3d surface plot like this, link available here :

https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/
[image]

But the problem is that I only have limited data available where I only have data for the peak location and the height of peak but the rest of the data is missing. In the example z-data need 25 X 25 values 625 data points to generate a valid surface plot.

My data looks something like this:
[image: DataTable_1]

So my question is that, is it possible to use some polynomial function with the peak location value as a constrain to generate Z-data based on the information I have?

Open to any discussion. Any form of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Though I don't like this form of interpolation, which is pretty artificial, you can use the following trick:

F(P) = (Σ Fk / d(P, Pk)) / (Σ 1 / d(P, Pk))

P is the point where you interpolate and Pk are the known peak positions. d is the Euclidean distance. (This gives sharp peaks; the squared distance gives smooth ones.)

Unfortunately, far from the peaks this formula tends to the average of the Fk, giving an horizontal surface that is above some of the Fk, giving downward peaks. You can work around this by adding fake peaks of negative height around your data set, to lower the average.

Comment: Hello @Yves, thank you for the suggestion! Would to clarify what on Fk. Is this an arbitrary value/ fixed value?

Comment: @user2232355: that's your peaks.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean. So Pk is individual peak whereas Fk is the sum of peak values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user2232355: why the sum ?? Call it Zk if you prefer.

Comment: ohhhh that is just the height. Sorry man, my brain stopped working for a while just now. Please forgive me for the dumb question. I will try it out.